# How To Return Rows Where The Date In One Column Is Closest To (Without Exceeding) The Date In Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I've inherited a database that tracks--among a ton of other information--unit prices over time and orders placed for particular products. I need my query to return only the rows where the value in column `effectiveDate` is closest to without exceeding the value in column `OrderDate` (in order to find the `unitprice` at the time the order was placed). The linked image shows the latest iteration of my query and its results. I've also tried `GROUP BY puph.productID`, but the results returned have the earliest rather than the latest `effectiveDate`.

In short, how do I return only those rows with the latest `effectiveDate` at the time of the `OrderDate`?

[image: Check Image]

Comment: Why mysql version?

Comment: This is not a complete question, because you neglected to include your code.  Please do so.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

**mysql v8.0**, you can use `row_number()`.

```
select * from (select o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, puph.productID, puph.unitprice, puph.effectiveDate
        , row_number() over (partition by o.orderID order by puph.effectiveDate desc) as rn
    from orders orders
    join `order details` od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    join productunitpricehistory puph on od.ProductID = puph.productID
    where puph.effectiveDate <= o.OrderDate
    ) t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.OrderID
```

or older version of `mysql`, you can use `max()` function.

```
select o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, puph.productID, puph.unitprice
, max(puph.effectiveDate) as effectiveDate
from orders orders
join `order details` od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
join productunitpricehistory puph on od.ProductID = puph.productID
where puph.effectiveDate <= o.OrderDate
group by o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, puph.productID, puph.unitprice
order by o.OrderID
```

Comment: The first method seems to work, but the `rn` column does not iterate. Is that expected?

Comment: depends on the partition by, try to change it o.orderID